# Does Zookeeper store persistent data for Hbase

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have totally 10 nodes. 3 nodes are running Zookeeper, the rest 7 nodes are running HDFS and Hbase. And Hbase has stored many data. I initialized Zookeeper nodes by mistake`(I'm using Cloudera, by mistake clicked the Initialize Button)`. I'd like to know did those 3 Zookeeper nodes lost the persistent data which might be Hbase mata data. Or say, Hbase store Meta data in Hmaster while Zookeeper just store some memory data.

Answer (score 1):

HBase stores all metadata in special `meta` table but not in Zookeeper. Zookeeper is used only for coordination and transient operations.

From [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/10/what-are-hbase-znodes/) article in Cloudera blog:

> In Apache HBase, ZooKeeper coordinates, communicates, and shares state
>   between the Masters and RegionServers. HBase has a design policy of
>   using ZooKeeper only for transient data (that is, for coordination and
>   state communication). **Thus if the HBase’s ZooKeeper data is removed,
>   only the transient operations are affected** — data can continue to be
>   written and read to/from HBase.

So everything should be OK.